# Gedit - how to set default encoding opening?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, gnome, character-encoding, gedit

I would like to somehow make Gedit on my sister's laptop to open text files in Windows1250 (CP1250-Winlatin2) encoding by default.

She has a plenty of ebooks in txt format and opening them in LibreOffice is not much comfortable.

I need to use Gedit or some similar GTK app, which is fully accessible by Orca Screenreader.

PS: running Vinux (based on Ubuntu Lucid Lynx) - more info here:

```
Running Ubuntu Linux, the Ubuntu 10.04 (lucid) release.
    GNOME: 2.30.0 (Ubuntu 2010-03-31)
    Kernel version: 2.6.32-22-generic (#36-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 3 22:02:19 UTC 2010)
    GCC: 4.4.3 (i486-Linux-gnu)
    Xorg: unknown (09 June 2010  10:55:28AM) (09 June 2010  10:55:28AM)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

create executable script `/usr/local/bin/geditwin`

```
#!/bin/sh
gedit --encoding=WINDOWS-1250 "$@"
```

and set it as default text editor in gnome. (right click on any text file, open with, remember...)